# Windbg script fails at alias expansion

Tags: windbg, portable-executable

The below windbg script always fails. I couldn't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
$$
$$ print all imported function names. ${$arg1} base address of a loaded image
$$

.block {
    .expr /s c++
    r $t1 = ${$arg1} + ((ntdll32!_IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)${$arg1})->e_lfanew
    r $t1 = ${$arg1} + ((ntdll32!_IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)@$t1)->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[1].VirtualAddress
    r $t0 = 0

    aS ${curImpDesc} ((Mydll_00!_IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR*)@$t1)[@$t0]
    .while (${curImpDesc}.Name != 0) {
        .printf "\n Imported Image: %ma\n", (${$arg1} + ${curImpDesc}.Name)

        r $t2 = 0
        r $t3 = ${$arg1} + ${curImpDesc}.OriginalFirstThunk

        aS ${curThunkData} ((Mydll_00!_IMAGE_THUNK_DATA32*)@$t3)[@$t2]
        .while (${curThunkData}.u1.AddressOfData != 0) {
            r $t4 = ${$arg1} + ${curThunkData}.u1.AddressOfData
            da &(((Mydll_00!_IMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME*)@$t4)->Name)
            r $t2 = @$t2 + 1
        }   
        r $t0 = @$t0 + 1
    }

    ad ${curImpDesc}
    ad ${curThunkData}
}
```

I wrote this script to print the imported image name , followed by all the imported function names. If I run this script line-by-line all going fine and I get the expected output. But if I run it as script file, then I am getting error
    0:065:x86> $$>a< "D:\import.wds" 0x74e70000

```
Unexpected character in '${curImpDesc}.Name != 0) {;....
```

Comment: You probably need a `.block` *after* creating the alias.

Comment: what is ntdll32 your own module of that name ? does it have the type informatation? is it loaded always ? this is one unportable crash prone error prone script ? first split that loops  start doing it line by line print out everything debugging this might be nightmare  if you are just interested in imports to a module dump this script and use  windbg command !showimports 7exxxx  alias expansion is not your only problem there appears to be n number of problems in the script